# javascript change the clip-path by clicking in the menu li

Tags: javascript, html, css, clip-path

i have problem with animation in javascript
i want to change clip-path value after click in to target from menu. 
for example after clicking in OFFER from menu i want to change OFFER section clip-path to "polygon(100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0)". 
so from start its invisible, but after click, one section i want to get shape from final clip-path value, and the other section have to get start value, and they are invisible.

thank you

```
const about = document.getElementById("about");
const offer = document.getElementById("offer");
const realize = document.getElementById("realize");
const contact = document.getElementById("contact");
const li = [...document.querySelectorAll("#menu li")];
const main = [...document.querySelectorAll("main section")];
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

function hide(target) {
  let value = window
    .getComputedStyle(target, null)
    .getPropertyValue("clip-path");
  if (target.style.clipPath === value) {
    main.forEach(
      element => (element.style.clipPath = "polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 0, 100% 0)")
    );
    target.style.clipPath = "polygon(100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0)";
  } else {
    console.log(target);
    console.log(value);
  }
}

function btn_hide() {
  btn.style.display = "none";
}

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  hide(about), btn_hide();
});
li[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  hide(about);
});
li[1].addEventListener("click", function() {
  hide(offer);
});
li[2].addEventListener("click", function() {
  hide(realize);
});
li[3].addEventListener("click", function() {
  hide(contact);
});
```

Comment: ok i already solved it, there was missing "px" after "0". sorry about that

Comment: you don't really need `px` after `0` of you are talking about the `0` inside the clip-path